# Adding javascript variable to html div tag

Tags: php, javascript

I want to know if it's possible to add a javascript variable to html div tag just like php For example:

```
    $id = 1;
    <div id="test'.$id.'"></div>

<script>
var id = '1';
</script>
<div id="test..???.??"></div>
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do here? Is that all the code that you have ?

Comment: {$id} needs `<?php ?>` tags

Comment: i edited.. check..just want to get the javascript variable and insert into the div tag.

Comment: You are possible asking this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801729/passing-data-to-a-jquery-click-function

Comment: I think this is closely related to what you're asking, and unfortunately the answer is no....you can't use javascript variables in-line like that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304014/javascript-variable-inside-string-without-concatenation-like-php

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805481/change-div-id-into-javascript-variable

Answer (score 7):

Not as simply as that, no.  You *can* do something like:

```
<script>
  var id = '1';
</script>
```

and then later:

```
<script>
  document.writeln('<div id="' + id + '">');
</script>

...

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<div id="id_change"></div>    
<script>
var id = 1;
var set_id = document.getElementById("id_change").id + id;
document.getElementById("id_change").id = set_id;
</script>
```

Hope this answers your question

**EDIT**

Put the `<script>` code after the `div` else it wont find the `div`

Answer (score 0):

You could use Jquery's .attr() method?
Take a look here: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

http://jsfiddle.net/PxUqU/2/

```
var currrentID = $("div").attr("id");
var someInt = 1;
$("div").attr("id", currrentID+someInt);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div"),
    newId = 1;

divs[0].setAttribute("id", newId);
```